# Concatenate identity matrix to each vector

Tags: python, keras, concatenation, reshape

I want to modify my input by adding several different suffixes to the input vectors. For example, if the (single) input is `[1, 5, 9, 3]` I want to create three vectors (stored as matrix) like this:

```
[[1, 5, 9, 3, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 5, 9, 3, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 5, 9, 3, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Of course, this is just one observation so the input to the model is `(None, 4)` in this case. The simple way is to prepare the input data somewhere else (numpy most probably) and adjust the shape of input accordingly. That I can do but I would prefer doing it inside TensorFlow/Keras.

I have isolated the problem into this code:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Lambda


def build_model(dim_input: int, dim_eye: int):
    input = Input((dim_input,))
    concat = Lambda(lambda x: concat_eye(x, dim_input, dim_eye))(input)
    return Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[concat])


def concat_eye(x, dim_input, dim_eye):
    x = K.reshape(x, (-1, 1, dim_input))
    x = K.repeat_elements(x, dim_eye, axis=1)
    eye = K.expand_dims(K.eye(dim_eye), axis=0)
    eye = K.tile(eye, (-1, 1, 1))
    out = K.concatenate([x, eye], axis=2)
    return out


def main():
    import numpy as np

    n = 100
    dim_input = 20
    dim_eye = 3

    model = build_model(dim_input, dim_eye)
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

    x_train = np.zeros((n, dim_input))
    y_train = np.zeros((n, dim_eye, dim_eye + dim_input))
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem seems to be in the `-1` in `shape` argument in `tile` function. I tried to replace it with `1` and `None`. Each has its own error:

- `-1`: error during `model.fit`

  ```
  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected multiples[0] >= 0, but got -1
  ```
- `1`: error duting `model.fit`

  ```
  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [32,3,20] vs. shape[1] = [1,3,3]
  ```
- `None`: error during `build_model`:

  ```
  Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, 1, 1). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`K.shape()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/aa0f12ce9eacd70932466d248fde746e0b0dfa0d/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L538) instead to get the **symbolic shape** of input tensor. That's because the batch size is `None` and therefore passing `K.int_shape(x)[0]` or `None` or `-1` as a part of the second argument of `K.tile()` would not work:

```
eye = K.tile(eye, (K.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I have previously tried `x.shape[0]` but that didn't work.